# value doesn't bind to selector at angular 6

Tags: angular, data-binding, binding

binding fail @ angular 6

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Tour of Heroes';

}

<sa-big-breadcrumbs [items]="['Category', '{{title}}' ]" class="classbig"></sa-big-breadcrumbs>
```

big-breadcrumbs.component.ts

```
  selector: 'sa-big-breadcrumbs',
  template: `
    <div class="row">
      <h4 class="header">
        <i class="fa-{{icon}}"></i> {{items[0]}} <span *ngFor="let item of items.slice(1)"> > {{item}}</span>
      </h4>
    </div>
  `,
```

Throw error,
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors....

I need to replace it so that it can put into proper html format for the translate to do translation
Eg below:

```
<div class="row">
  <h4 class="header">
    <i class="fa-{{icon}}"></i> {{items[0]}} <span *ngFor="let item of items.slice(1)"> > {{item}}</span>
  </h4>
</div>
```

to be replaced with

```
<div class="row">
  <h4 class="header">
    <i class="fa-{{icon}}"></i> {{items[0]}} <span *ngFor="let item of items.slice(1)"> >  {{ 'item' | translate }}</span>
  </h4>
</div>
```

So that at final html it can come out with

Category > Tour of Heroes (normal)
Catégorie> Tour of Heroes (translated via library detect)

any way to bind value from ts to html?

Comment: On the first look, it looks right. Please provide the code of your component

Comment: string interpolation braces is invalid in js expression. replace  `[items]="['Category', '{{title}}' ]"` with `[items]="['Category', title]"`

Answer (score 1):

This is not correctly formed:

```
[items]="['Category', '{{title}}' ]"
```

it should be something like:

```
[items]="['Category', title ]"
```

Answer (score 0):

string interpolation braces is invalid in js expression. replace  `[items]="['Category', '{{title}}' ]"` with `[items]="['Category', title]"`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to replace the code below.

[items]="['Category', '{{title}}' ]"

To

[items]="['Category', title ]"

And than change also To....

```html
<div class="row">
  <h4 class="header">
    <i class="fa-{{icon}}"></i> {{items[0] | translate}} <span *ngFor="let item of items.slice(1)"> >  {{ 'item[0]' | translate }}</span>
  </h4>
</div>
```